# USB Keyboard most keys not working

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I bought a new wireless USB keyboard, a HP pavilion 600. But it doesn't really work.

Some keys do work like the home button and calculator, but I can´t type and use the arrow keys.

I'm on the 18.04 LTS version of Ubuntu and I have no idea how to fix this. On the same PC, I have Windows and the keyboard works perfect on there.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: What is your OS and version?

Comment: It is on a HP Zbook 15 that has Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.